# Partition function for a bidisperse packing of soft-core particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, soft-matter

My goal is to study the nematic order in bidisperse packings of soft-core spheroidal particles of identical aspect ratio with harmonic repulsion from a statistical mechanics point of view by adapting Onsager's hard rod model. I found out this was performed for monodisperse packings of hard-core spheroidal particles in *Physical Review E* **96**, 022704 (2017), available [here](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:a2cb0e92-bad3-40c3-a31d-6111e81be2b9/datastreams/ATTACHMENT01) for free or on the [APS website](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.96.022704) through paywall.

For a monodisperse packing of $N$ particles, we can consider that these are indistinguishable, therefore with $\mathcal{V}_{ij}(\vec{r}_{i},\vec{r}_{j}\in\mathbb{R}^3,\hat{\textbf{I}}_i,\hat{\textbf{I}}_j\in\mathbb{S}^2)$ the interacting potential between particles $i$ and $j$ — which depends on their respective positions and orientations — we can write the partition function to a multiplicative constant depending on kinetic parameters
$$
Z = \frac{1}{N!} \int\ldots\int d^{3N}\vec{r}~d^{2N}\hat{\textbf{I}} ~\exp\left(-\frac{1}{k_BT}\sum_{i<j}^N~\mathcal{V}_{ij}(\vec{r}_{i},\vec{r}_{j},\hat{\textbf{I}}_i,\hat{\textbf{I}}_j)\right)
$$

If I now consider a packing of $N/2$ "small" and $N/2$ "big" particles, the potential $\mathcal{V}_{ij}$ will depend on the sizes of both interacting particles. How can I then adapt the partition function?

Thank you very much for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, apart from the fact that instead of a factor $N!$ at the denominator you will have a factor $(N/2)! \cdot (N/2)!$.

The potential term will be formally the same, including the interactions between A particles and B particles, between A and A and between B and B. In conclusion:

$$Z \propto \frac 1{\left(\frac N 2!\right)^2} \int \dots \int d^{\frac{3N}2} \mathbf r_a \cdot d^{\frac{3N}2} \mathbf r_b \cdot d^{N} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{I}}_a \cdot d^{N}  \mathbf{\hat{I}}_b \cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{k_BT}\sum_{i<j}^N~\mathcal{V}_{ij}(\mathbf{r}_{i},\mathbf{r}_{j},\hat{\textbf{I}}_i,\hat{\textbf{I}}_j)\right)$$

where $\mathbf r_i,\mathbf r_i \in \{\mathbf r_a,\mathbf r_b\}$ and $ \mathbf{\hat{I}}_i,\mathbf{\hat{I}}_j \in \{\mathbf{\hat{I}}_a,\mathbf{\hat{I}}_b\}$.